# Rest call from webViewDidFinishLoad cause error

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9

When i call getProfile method from viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getProfile];

}
```

it success

```
-(void)getProfile
{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];



    NSString *tempurl= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@11155/person/@self",baseUrlSecure];
    tempurl = [tempurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempurl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:gWCToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"WCToken"];
    [request addValue:gWCTrustedToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"WCTrustedToken"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {



        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [Alert showAlertWithTitle:@"M2All" andWithMessage:error.localizedDescription onView:self andErrorCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",error.code]];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary *dictResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *arrError = [dictResult objectForKey:@"errors"];
            if(arrError.count >0)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [Alert showAlertWithTitle:@"M2All" andWithMessage:[[arrError objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"errorMessage"] onView:self andErrorCode:[[arrError objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"errorCode"]];

                });
                return;
            }


                 }

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

but same calling from  webViewDidFinishLoad then getting error

i don't know what is the problem

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
        [self getProfile];

}
```

Comment: what the error u get..

Comment: errors =     (
                {
            errorCode = CWXFR0220E;
            errorKey = "ERR_COOKIE_TO_TOKEN_UID_MISMATCH";
            errorMessage = "CWXFR0220E: A security error has occurred because the user ID 74007 in WCToken does not match the user ID -1002 in the WC_USER_ACTIVITY cookie.";
            errorParameters = "[74007, -1002]";
        }
    );
}

Comment: its not a common error bro, check once in your back end side

Comment: backend person saying that your request not coming to the server

Comment: he said lie , print echo once ,

Comment: else try in manually on backend

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser cookies and try again. I faced the similar problem. I cleared the browser cache and it's working fine for me

Comment: Not sure if that really answers the question. How says that he is using a browswer?